# Javascript notifications in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, background, notifications, alarm

I'm trying to make a sort of alarm clock web application and I noticed that I was having a problem where the audio file wouldn't play and the title-bar wouldn't flash if Chrome or the web application's tab wasn't in focus.

I found an answer here saying that Chrome runs in separate processes or threads, so I would need some inter-process programming or something, but I couldn't find any examples about how to do this, all I could find were ways to pause the JavaScript in the background until focus was given back to the tab or Chrome. Obviously, this is useless, as the point of the application is to provide notifications while the tab or Chrome is not focused.

The application works fine in other browsers, just not Chrome. Does anyone know how I can make the titlebar flash and play an audio file even if Chrome or the web app's tab is not in focus?

Comment: one hacky way is to never stop playing audio, even if it means looping a track of silence. you can keep some phones awake like that too. once chrome puts your page to rest, almost all hope is lost.

Comment: So, essentially endlessly loop a silent track and then when my alarm goes off, switch the silent track for the alarm sound? This sounds like a pain; is there a way to disable this functionality in Chrome?

Comment: not from JS, but maybe there is a pref the user can change. if you want to be the fastest racer and everyone else is fast, you have to cut some corners to win...

Comment: judging from the crickets in here, my audio hack might just be the only way to keep your foot in the door. I have a media player in html5 and i  noticed that it keeps executing js the whole time, but i've not seen any other web pages/apps that don't go to snooze if left alone.

Comment: @dandavis, I'll give it a try. I haven't had the chance to try it yet. Did you just use the <audio> tag?

Comment: @dandavis I tried the audio hack, but it's not working at all. I still get the same problem. This is what I did: 
`<audio loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay">
 <source src="ping.wav" type="audio/wav">
 <embed src="ping.wave">
</audio>`